# matching patterns with an optional string

Tags: java, regex

In a Java app, I use this regex: **(\w+)_\d** to match patterns of this form:

```
apples_1
oranges_2
```

and then I use the first capturing group value (apples, oranges).

However, I now have a new request to also match these strings:

```
applesdrp_1
orangesdrp_2
```

where 'drp' is a fixed 3 character string, and the same values as before need to be captured: apples, oranges

So for example, if I use this regex: **(\w+)(?:drp)?_\d**
it will do the work on apples_1, but not for applesdrp_1.

Is there a way to do that with a regex?

Comment: `\w+` is greedy.  It will always consume the optional "drp", because it is optional.  You need to make the first match non greedy.  `(\w+?)(?:drp)?_\d`

Comment: this is not a question this is *send me teh regex codez* list of requirements with a completely useless question at the end of the requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a non-greedy quantifier:

```
(\w+?)(?:drp)?_\d
```

In this way `\w+?` will take characters until it find `"drp_N"` or `"_N"` (where N is a digit).

If you use a greedy quantifier, `\w+` takes all possible character (including the underscore and the digit since they are included in `\w`) and then gives back characters one by one until `(?:drp)?_\d` succeeds. But since `(?:drp)?` is optional, the regex engine stops to backrack when it find `_N`.

Comment: Thank you! I knew I missing a little thing :) Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can - one way would be using a negative lookbehind, to make sure, that the drp is forced outside the group, if it is present

```
(\w+)(?<!drp)(?:drp)?_\d+
```

See https://regex101.com/r/jJ1rM4/3 for a demo

Comment: This is also a great solution. Thanks!